# SCCM Remote Control: Can you have multiple connection to same host?

Tags: remote-desktop, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

Is it possible via the remote control feature of SCCM 2012 R2 SP1 to have more than one connection to a client?  I.e. If two or three support staff want to remote into the same client at the same time to help each other.

Can this be done via a configuration change?

Comment: If SCCM client is on the support computers, you could always remote the tech's computer which is remoting the client.

Answer (score 1):

As useful as that would be, unfortunately the remote control feature within SCCM only allows **one** active connection.  You'll get the following message if you try to remote control a host which already has an active connection:

[image: Good old error message]

I've double checked the Client Settings for remote tools and there is no feature to extend the allowed amount.